# Replacing text with special character in linux shell script?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, sed

I am currently working on a project porting a lot of C programs onto a new Linux system. My goal is to automate most of the simple repetitive errors if possible.

Right now I am dealing with a lot of invalid assignments of NULL, which should be '\0' on that specific line(s). Example:

```
attribute = NULL;
```

should be

```
attribute = '\0';
```

I have a list of all lines where this error occurs. So now all I need to do is create a script that changes NULL to \0. This is the line of code I have tried, with different variations:

```
sed -i "${1}s/NULL/\\0/" ${2}
```

${1} being the line the error is occuring and ${2} being the filename.

Edit:

Instead of replacing NULL with \0, it is being replaced as 'NULL'. I need a command that will replace NULL with the characters \ and 0, not the special character.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the single quotes in the replacement string?  It's not clear what you want.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question or a problem description in your post. Assuming your command does not work as expected, show how you call it, what actual result/output you get and what you would expect to get. Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: @Bodo I apologize. I edited the post with a little more information, that's my fault. Let me know if you need any more clarification

Comment: I really hope for your sake you have version control in place so you can check that your replacement script doesn't go haywire and wreck everything. `git reset --hard` is a great way to back out of a `sed` script gone awry.

Comment: @tadman The script will affect one file at a time, not every file at once. Each is individually pulled from a repository and pushed back, so if anything goes wrong its not final.

Comment: At least you've got that. This can be done with `perl` or Visual Studio Code, or any editor which supports regular expressions in replacements. You're not stuck with `sed`.

Comment: @tadman Very true, I just assumed there could be an easy fix in my formatting of the sed command. I will start looking into other options. Thanks!

Comment: Forgive the obvious question, but why would you want to port the C and not compile it?? (are you saying the "new Linux system" doesn't recognize `NULL` when compiling???)

Comment: @david We are switching from HP to Linux. There are a lot of compiler errors that went undetected before. The specific warning I'm getting in this example is "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast". Its a char variable, so I'm changing it to \0.

Comment: That is telling me you have a problem with your `type` for those variables. Presumably `attribute` was a *pointer*, but in your transfer it is not showing up as an integer type. That is not uncommon if you are missing a *forward-declaration* for the type because in C an unspecified type defaults to `int`. `NULL` is a pointer. So your error `"assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"` says the compiler thinks you are attempting to assign `NULL` to an `int`. That is NOT an indicator that you need to parse and change `NULL` to `'\0'`. It says you need to fix the type for `attribute`.

Comment: In other words -- I sure hope you are saving a backup of all your C files -- unchanged. You may find the substitutions you are making were not the way to address the compiler issues you are having....

Comment: @David There are backups. Definitely going to have to do testing regardless, there are over 200 C files we are porting and some have hundreds of warnings to fix. I was just recently assigned this project as an intern, and was given a list of common errors and how to fix them (this was on that list). May test certain things, including this, sooner rather than later to make sure its being done properly. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I recall  having to identify and correct small differences between two independently developed ascent vehicle load simulations, roughly 750K lines of FORTRAN each -- as a co-op student at Rockwell. (similar to intern) The simple solutions are usually the correct ones. In your case, you are most likely missing a header file that provides the pointer declarations that will allow the code to compile as-is. Search (`grep`) the code for `'[*][ ]*attribute'` to find the declaration and then search for the `type` that is to the left of `'*'`. That will identify the pointer type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file
attribute = NULL;

$ sed 's/NULL/'\''\\0'\''/' file
attribute = '\0';
```

You might want to add word boundaries so you don't replace strings with `NULL` in them. You must be using GNU sed for that usage of `-i` so:

```
$ cat file
attribute = NULL;
FOONULLBAR

$ sed 's/NULL/'\''\\0'\''/' file
attribute = '\0';
FOO'\0'BAR

$ sed 's/\<NULL\>/'\''\\0'\''/' file
attribute = '\0';
FOONULLBAR
```

You may want to also consider defining a variable `NUL = '\0'` in a common header and using that in place of `NULL` instead of hard-coding `\0` everywhere.

To only do a substitution on a specific line number that's stored in a variable then:

```
$ lineNr=1; sed "$lineNr"'s/NULL/'\''\\0'\''/' file
attribute = '\0';
FOONULLBAR

$ lineNr=2; sed "$lineNr"'s/NULL/'\''\\0'\''/' file
attribute = NULL;
FOO'\0'BAR
```

or if you don't mind doubling up on backslashes and know you won't have anything else in your sed command that the shell could interpret/expand (as is true for this specific case):

```
$ lineNr=1; sed "${lineNr}s/NULL/'\\\\0'/" file
attribute = '\0';
FOONULLBAR

$ lineNr=2; sed "${lineNr}s/NULL/'\\\\0'/" file
attribute = NULL;
FOO'\0'BAR
```

Comment: That sounds like a really good idea to define a new variable to '\0'. I may end up doing that actually.

Comment: The command you listed works great as is. The only issue is I only want to replace NULL with '\0' on specific lines (${1} in my example). But it may be easy enough to fix with your advice at the end. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to target a specific line number. Hopefully it's obvious that I suggested `NUL` as the variable name since that's what `\0` **is** in Ascii - the NUL character (not to be confused with the NULL pointer in C).

Comment: That worked great, really appreciate the fast response!